# How can I config apache shiro without xml document

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, shiro

I need to deploy shiro for My j2ee app. But I use Annotation configuration in my whole project. So I don't want to deploy shiro with xml. But I didn't find any demo without xml in google. Can't someone can give me a hand to write some demo for me? Thanks!

Comment: If you give us information on how you want to configure shiro, given a properties file for example, I can give it a shot.